# OpenCV Какие есть рекомендации для устранения искажений камеры?

Tags: opencv

Использую поиск шаблона "шахматной доски" для исправления искажений линз камеры.

Возникло несколько вопросов:

- Есть ли какие рекомендации для получения хорошего результата?
- Зависит ли результат от количества квадратов на доске?

UPD:

Наткнулся на [статью](https://calib.io/blogs/knowledge-base/calibration-best-practices)

Насколько верны приведенные в ней рекомендации?

Comment: Уточните, что значит метка unidostortion ?

Comment: @Kromster, подразумевался метод OpenCV [`undistort`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga69f2545a8b62a6b0fc2ee060dc30559d). Удалил этот тег